# Is it possible to use the swa-cli with existing Azure resources?

Tags: azure, swa-cli

I have restricted access to a client Azure Resources. The client created a default static-webapp (let's call it `"my-mvp"`) and a virtual machine for me to deploy a app and a api. I am not allowed to create any new static-webapps or any other service. When using the `swa deploy` -command it does not allow me to connect the existing source.

How can I link `my-mvp` project to the existing my-mvp static webapp in Azure?

Deployment on my own Azure subscription works just fine when using the `swa deploy` command and creating a new Static WebApp. Also my `.yml` configuration works fine so I got it all working. This question has merly to do with the usage of the `swa-cli`.

While trying out the swa-cli with `swa deploy` -command with the following configuration (swa-cli.config.json);

```
{
  "$schema": "https://aka.ms/azure/static-web-apps-cli/schema",
  "configurations": {
    "my-mvp": {
      "appName": "my-mvp",
      "appLocation": "./apps/frontend",
      "outputLocation": "build",
      "appBuildCommand": "npm run build",
      "run": "npm start",
      "appDevserverUrl": "http://localhost:3000",
      "apiLocation": "./apps/backend",
      "apiBuildCommand": "npm run build",
      "apiRunCommand": "npm run start:dev",
      "apiDevserverUrl": "http://localhost:3002",
      "apiPort": 3002,
      "appPort": 3000,
      "subscriptionId": "omitted for obvious reasons",
      "resourceGroupName": "omitted for obvious reasons",
      "tenantId": "omitted for obvious reasons"
    }
  }
}
```

I got the following output;

```
Checking project "my-mvp" settings...
✖ The project "my-mvp" is linked to "DevOps"!
✖ Unlink the project from the "DevOps" provider and try again.
```

`my-mvp` is the name of the static-webapp resource in Azure DevOps were I'm trying to attach this project to.

If I rename the `appName` to something else it gives me the default options;

```
Checking project "my-other-mvp" settings...
? Would you like to create a new Azure Static Web Apps project? › (Y/n)
```

Because I'm not allowed to create any new Static Web App I press "n";

```
Checking project "my-other-mvp" settings...
✔ Would you like to create a new Azure Static Web Apps project? … no
✖ The provided project name "my-other-mvp" was not found.
```

If I press "Yes" the response is a RestError. If I enter "Yes" with the appName "my-mvp" it gives me the very first reponse.

Is it possible to use the `swa-cli` with existing resources?

Comment: Have you tried https://azure.github.io/static-web-apps-cli/docs/cli/swa-login before swa deploy?

Answer (score 0):

**You have to disconnect the existing app first!**

First, install the Azure CLI:
https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/cli/azure/install-azure-cli

After that, run the following command in your Terminal to login:

```
$ az login
```

If you use resource groups, set your default resource group with this command:

```
$ az configure --defaults group=YOUR-RESOURCE-GROUP
```

Finally, disconnect the web app with the following command

```
$ az staticwebapp disconnect -n APP-NAME
```

For you, it should be:

```
$ az staticwebapp disconnect -n my-mvp
```